# How to open BerkleyDB file with multiple databases?

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm trying to read data from BerkeleyDB with multiple database inside. If I open it as in the source code below only the first DB is accessed. How to get access to the others?

```cs
    using System;
    using BerkeleyDB;

    namespace WalletParser
    {
        public static class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Database db = Database.Open(@"foo.db", new DatabaseConfig{ReadOnly = true});
                Console.WriteLine(db.HasMultiple);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another Database.Open overload that gets database name as a parameter:

```cs
static Database Open(string Filename, string DatabaseName, DatabaseConfig cfg)
```